# MuleStudio file deleted while simple renaming

Tags: mule, mule-studio

In MuleStudio a simple rename script deletes files after a while. This is how the script looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.4.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp/current/mule-ftp.xsd">
    <flow name="ftp_ping_pong_testFlow1" doc:name="ftp_ping_pong_testFlow1" initialState="started" processingStrategy="queued-asynchronous">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\in\" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" fileAge="1000" pollingFrequency="1200">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="^.*\.csv$" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\in\" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']].temp" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="ftp_ping_pong_testFlow2" doc:name="ftp_ping_pong_testFlow2">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\in\" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" fileAge="1000" pollingFrequency="1200">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="^.*\.temp$" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\in\" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename'].replace('.temp','')]" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The script does nothing else but renames the file, than names it back. It makes no difference if I raise the fileAge or if I change the processing strategy or if I run it in MuleStudio or Mule Standalone. What is strange that it works for ~300 iterations but then it gets confused.

The error log what I get looks like:

```
WARN  2013-12-19 12:43:15,815 [Finalizer] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Failure trying to remove file C:\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\in\145278.csv.temp from list of files under processing
```

I have already lost a week with this issue, so any help would be much appreciated :)

Update:
I created two different apps. Here they are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule Links removed by Stackoverflow">
    <file:connector name="File_Connector_CSV"    autoDelete="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" readFromDirectory="C:\Users\gabor.bodo\MuleStudio\workspace\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\in" writeToDirectory="C:\Users\gabor.bodo\MuleStudio\workspace\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\out"/>
    <flow name="ftp_ping_pong_testFlow1" doc:name="ftp_ping_pong_testFlow1" initialState="started" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\gabor.bodo\MuleStudio\workspace\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\in\" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" fileAge="1000" pollingFrequency="1200" connector-ref="File_Connector_CSV"  >
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="^.*\.csv$" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <file:outbound-endpoint  outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']].temp" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="C:\Users\gabor.bodo\MuleStudio\workspace\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\out"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

And the second:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule links removed by Stackoverflow">
    <file:connector name="File" writeToDirectory="C:\Users\gabor.bodo\MuleStudio\workspace\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\in" readFromDirectory="C:\Users\gabor.bodo\MuleStudio\workspace\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\out" autoDelete="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow name="ftp_ping_pong_player2Flow1" doc:name="ftp_ping_pong_player2Flow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\gabor.bodo\MuleStudio\workspace\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\out" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="^.*\.temp$" caseSensitive="true"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\gabor.bodo\MuleStudio\workspace\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\in\" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename'].replace('.temp','')]" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I ran the test with 7 test files, and as usual the files started to disappear. From the combine logs, here is the last appearance of one of the files:

```
    INFO  2013-12-20 17:58:13,843 [[ping_pong_player1].File_Connector_CSV.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\in\09.csv
    INFO  2013-12-20 17:58:14,519 [[ping_pong_player1].File_Connector_CSV.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: C:\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\out\09.csv.temp
    INFO  2013-12-20 17:58:14,812 [[ping_pong_player2].File.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\out\09.csv.temp
    INFO  2013-12-20 17:58:15,437 [[ping_pong_player2].File.dispatcher.402] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: C:\ftp_ping_pong_test\src\test\in\09.csv
```

After these log entries this file simply disappeared without any no further trace in logs.
I have observed that even if in MuleStudio there is a default value defined for File Age, the value is not represented in the XML file, this is why Player2, has no File Age defined.

I can about a possible scenario:
- Player1, reads the csv file and creates the temp. Player 2 reads the temp and writes back the csv. Player1 deletes the csv, believing it is still the original file. In this case Player1 is too slow, lets Player2 intervene and this can happen if Player2 has no File Age. - I have to retest this with File Age value settings accordingly.But it does not explain why happens this very rarely.

Thanks,
Gabor

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, si far I have tried the followings: different settings for polling (500,1000,1500,3000) and fileAge (400,600,900,1000,1500,1600,4500) and their combinations; different endpoints: file, FTP and their combinations; putting them in different flows, projects; deploying them in MuleStudio, Standalone on different OS-es (win7, Ubuntu) and their combinations (FTP on Ubuntu, Mule on Win7); different processing strategy: synchronous, queued-asynchronous; with maven and without maven; what else should be tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to figure out what was the problem after countless of experiments.

It seems that when mule is launching an application the File Age property will be checked only once, and not for each flow separately (maybe it is normal but I did not expect this behaviour). Even with different flows, it doesn't matter what is the File Age property as long as it is less than the standard kick time of Mule (says 5000 ms, but actually it is 50000 ms - someone added one zero in plus somewhere).

So what happened, that Player1 and Player2 were always trying to read, copy and delete all the files in the same time. It was just a question of when until the scenario described by me above happened.

The solution now works well, by making two separate applications with big enough FileAge (Attention that it is not enough that you have a FileAge defined in MuleStudio, it has to be in the XML as well!).

Hope it saves time for someone and thanks for all the good intention!

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
I know your feeling. When you add the **File Connector**, uncheck **Auto Delete** in the **General** tab:

[image]

Comment: I checked, but on the interface, there is no option to "uncheck" this option. For <file:inbound-endpoint autoDelete is invalid option - if I add it in the XML. The tag <file:connector is "Invalid content was found starting with element 'file:connector'"...

Comment: autoDelete is invalid option for <file:outbound-endpoint as well

Comment: If it helps, here are the version informations: *
* Mule ESB and Integration Platform                                  *
* Version: 3.4.0 Build: c8afb471                                     *
* MuleSoft, Inc.                                                     *
* For more information go to http://www.mulesoft.org
* Server started: 18/12/13 10:19                                     
* JDK: 1.7.0_45 (mixed mode)                 
* OS: Windows 7 - Service Pack 1 (6.1, x86)* Host: user-PC (192.168.0.202)

Comment: No, you don't have to write it on the xml. I forgot to say **File Inboud Endpoint**. It doesn't appear with the **Outbound**.

Comment: Mule Studio - Tooling for Mule ESB

Version: 3.5.0
Build Id: 201312091746

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. It is the **File Connector**, not the Endpoint. I'm sorry. I updated my answer.

Comment: It is not possible to specify auto delete for File Inbound: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Endpoint+Reference

Comment: Yep, I said 8 minutes ago, it's **File Connector**, not Endpoint as I said before.

Comment: I added a File Connector, and unchecked the Auto Delete option. In this case, however the processor does not remove the file AFTER it has been processed. This is not the required behavior. The file should be removed after successfully processed. If a File Global (even with Auto Delete checked) element is defined than the files are not processed but only once - which is not the required behavior. I will try to create two separate applications with File Global Elements. Let's see...

Comment: I retested again with Auto Delete and without streaming, but I got the same result. I will update the question with the situation.